# Errors Implementing Google ReCaptcha (v2) on Custom Wordpress Registration Form

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, recaptcha

I am working on creating a custom registration plugin for an online community based publication that I work on. The site needs a custom solution due to the way we manage users and I think I've got the plugin 95% percent there. The final thing I am trying to implement but having a problem with is Google Recaptcha.

Right now I have this divided into several files. The form itself, which is built using Zurb's Foundation. There is a javascript file which then uses jquery to watch the form and collect the response when the user hits submit. It then removes all the form elements and appends a success or failure notice to the page. Lastly, there are a set of functions which create a new user using the information passed to the function from the ajax jquery call.

I have the code to render the captcha in the form's html. It works fine but where I hit a problem is with checking and validating the response. I can't seem to get that php right. (see the first two if statements in the register new users function.)

Much of the code is probably a bit ameaturish. I'm still new to php and learning as I go. Am I calling the captcha response correctly? I can't figure out why I can't seem to get and parse the response correctly.

The html form looks like this:

```
<div class="vb-registration-form">
<form data-abide novalidate id="reg-form" class="registration-form">
<!-- The form goes here. I have removed it from this post to avoid making the question too long. -->
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_sitekey_is_entered_here"></div>
<fieldset class="large-6 columns">
<button class="button" type="submit" id="btn-new-user" value="Submit" display="none">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="large-6 columns">
<button class="button" type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
</fieldset>
</div>
</div> <!-- close vb-reg form -->
</form>
<div class="row">
<div class="medium-12 columns"  id="successfulregistration" style="display:none">
<div class="callout success">
<h2>Thank you for registering.</h2>
<p>Please look for an email from us confirming your registration. We will confirm your account within 3-5 business days.</p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="medium-12 columns"  id="unsuccessfulregistration" style="display:none;" >
<div class="callout alert">
<h2>There was a problem...</h2>
<p class="responsemsg"></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The javascript file that watches the form and sends an ajax request with the submitted form data to my functions looks like this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
  var form = document.getElementById('reg-form');
  /*** When user clicks on button... ***/
  $('#btn-new-user').click( function(event) {
  var elements = this.elements;
  /*** Prevent default action, so when user clicks button he doesn't navigate   away from page**/
  if (event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    event.returnValue = false;
  }
// Collect data from inputs
var reg_nonce = $('#vb_new_user_nonce').val();
var reg_user  = $('#vb_username').val();
var reg_pass  = $('#vb_pass').val();
var reg_mail  = $('#vb_email').val();
var first_name  = $('#vb_FirstName').val();
var last_name  = $('#vb_LastName').val();
var inst_affil = $('#vb_institutionalaffiliation').val();
var location = $('#vb_location').val();
var twitter = $('#vb_twitter').val();
var bio = $('#vb_bio').val();
var captcha_response = $('#g-recaptcha-response').val();
var checkboxValues = [];
$('input[name=signup]:checked').map(function() {
  checkboxValues.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(checkboxValues);
/**
* AJAX URL where to send data
* (from localize_script)
*/
var ajax_url = vb_reg_vars.vb_ajax_url;
// Data to send. The register_user action corresponds to the action in functions.php
data = {
  action: 'register_user',
  nonce: reg_nonce,
  user: reg_user,
  pass: reg_pass,
  mail: reg_mail,
  firstname: first_name,
  lastname: last_name,
  institution: inst_affil,
  location: location,
  twitterhandle: twitter,
  userbio: bio,
  volunteerdates: checkboxValues,
  captcha: captcha_response
};
console.log(data);
console.log(data.user);
// Do AJAX request
$.post( ajax_url, data, function(response) {
// If we have response
if( response ) {
  if( response === '1' ) {
    // If user is created
    $('.vb-registration-form').remove();
    $('#successfulregistration').show();
    console.log(response);
  } else {
    $('.vb-registration-form').remove();
    $('#unsuccessfulregistration').show();
    $('.responsemsg').append(response);
    console.log(response);
  }
}
});
});
});
```

The php functions that check this data and create the user look like:

```
function vb_reg_new_user() {
  $privatekey = 'private_key_is_entered_here'
  $args = array(
    'body' => array(
      'secret' => $privatekey,
      'response' => stripslashes( esc_html ($_POST["captcha_response"] ) )
      ));
  $resp = wp_remote_post( 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', $args);
  $response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true);
// Verify nonce
  if( !isset( $_POST['nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['nonce'], 'vb_new_user' ) ) {
    die( 'Ooops, something went wrong, please try again later.' );
  } elseif ( $response != 'True'){
    die( 'Captcha error');
  } else {
    // Post values
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $email    = $_POST['mail'];
    $fname    = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lname    = $_POST['lastname'];
    $instaffil = $_POST['institution'];
    $loc       = $_POST['location'];
    $twitter  = $_POST['twitterhandle'];
    $bio  = $_POST['userbio'];
    $voldates = $_POST['volunteerdates'];
    $username = sanitize_text_field($username);
    $fname = sanitize_text_field($fname);
    $lname = sanitize_text_field($lname);
    $instaffil = sanitize_text_field($instaffil);
    $loc = sanitize_text_field($loc);
    $twitter  = sanitize_text_field($twitter);
    $bio  = sanitize_text_field($bio);
    $userdata = array(
    'user_login' => $username,
    'user_pass'  => $password,
    'user_email' => $email,
    'first_name' => $fname,
    'last_name' => $lname,
    'description' => $bio,
    'role' => 'pending'
    );

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

// Return
if( !is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
  echo '1';
  echo $response['success'];
  notifyadmin($email, $username, $fname, $lname);
  notifyuser($email, $fname, $lname);
} else {
  echo $user_id->get_error_message();
  echo $response['success'];
}
add_user_signupmeta($user_id, $voldates);
die();
}}
```

So my question is twofold. First, am I checking the captcha in the right place? This should be done in the php not the javascript, right? And second, where am I going wrong when trying to check the captcha response?

Comment: i don't see it in your code, but did you include the JS of the captcha ? (https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js)

Comment: Oh yeah its not there, but yes I have that enqueued and I check to make sure it is in fact loading. The captcha works up until its time to ping google's server and check the response

Comment: also i advice you to check this, it's complete way to use re-captcha with php https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php